# Reaching out to an employer regarding an offer letter

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-offer

Last week Monday, I was verbally told that I was chosen for a role within a moderately sized company (7000 employees). The HR employee told me on the same phone call that I would receive an offer letter via email within the next 48 hours.

After 4 days past, I reached out to the HR employee to just follow up on the conversation via email on Friday morning. I have **not** received any sort of response from her.

I understand that things come up (maybe she’s on vacation and forgot to tell me, she is sick, still trying to work out the contract, etc). I would like some advice on how to approach this going forward. I don’t want to continue to be a bother, but I have other offers to consider. Should I reach out to other HR employees, of which I have no connection with? Or should I continue to hold out and hope the HR employee gets back to me soon?

Again, I want to emphasize that I understand things come up in the workplace. I wouldn’t be worried if the HR rep hadn’t told me “you’ll receive the offer letter within 48 hours.” I appreciate any advice and or guidance. Thanks.

Comment: You can and should aggressively contact everyone involved, by phone. I'd just go to the office and talk to reception and get someone in HR and sort it out.  You have to CLOSE deals, it can be tricky sometimes.  Good luck!  Don't hesitate to phone everyone.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere well it has been a week since I last heard from her

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely ask other employees (from HR or not), if you know their contact information. What if that HR employee is on vacation and forgot to put an OOO message, or didn't tell her employees about you as a candidate? If you receive no reply, I wouldn't push too far; they could be unprofessionally ignoring you for a reason.

EDIT: I do want to mention HR and the hiring manager can be disconnected. Sometimes the hiring manager is at the mercy of HR and their hiring and onboarding policies, but sometimes HR can't get a hold of the hiring manager. This may be the case. I can speak from personal experience.